# Stick the toolbar to bottom

Tags: css, toolbar, footer, fixed

My code

```
.bid-toolbar {
    background:#FFCD2F !important;
    height:70px !important;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
```

I want to make the yellow toolbar stick to the bottom. I have tried a few times to make this toolbar to the bottom, but whenever I make it

```
fixed
```

, it goes up as I scroll the page down as you can see in the image below.

Comment: try adding !important or just give link to your page

Comment: !important to the position did you mean that?

Comment: Added !important, didn't change anything...

Answer (score 2):

Using `position: fixed` often causes problems in mobile browsers. You can use `display:flex` in combination with `overflow:auto` to get a fixed footer without using fixed postioning:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0pt;
        }
        .Frame {
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: column;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
        }
        .Row {
          flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        .Row.Expand {
          overflow: auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="Frame">
       <div class="Row Expand"><h2>Awesome content</h2></div>
       <div class="Row"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9L2reymy/2/

---

*This is the original answer, which hides the footer if the content is bigger than the screen height:*

I wrote [an article in my blog about fixed footers](https://pixelsvsbytes.com/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/) and implemented them with `display:table` instead. Here is the relevant code in a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0pt;
        }
        .Frame {
             display: table;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
        }
        .Row {
             display: table-row;
             height: 1px;
        }
        .Row.Expand {
             height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="Frame">
       <div class="Row Expand"><h2>Awesome content</h2></div>
       <div class="Row"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `position:fixed` make it `absolute` property of position like

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: It's still the same ;)

Comment: ok can you make a jsfiddle of this. because i am unable to get it why this is happening,it should be working.

Comment: ok right click on the element and inspect it and see whether the element is getting property from the class or not

Comment: I actually doing mobile apps hybrid on Intel XDK... not sure how to inspect it

Comment: ya but that's a html page right.so u can open it in browser and inspect it.or make a copy of that html page.

Answer (score 1):

```
position:absoulute; left:0px; bottom:0px; z-index:999;
```

Comment: put the div (bid-toolbar) at the bottom of the page. after "damaged photos" if it is the last div

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to keep the bid toolbar bottom try the this code and note I used an ID #bid_toolBar you can change it to class if you want to.

```
  $(document).ready( function() { 

       var bid_toolBarHeight = 0,
           bid_toolBarTop = 0,
           $bid_toolBar = $("#bid_toolBar");

       positionbid_toolBar();

       function positionbid_toolBar() {

                bid_toolBarHeight = $bid_toolBar.height();
                bid_toolBarTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-bid_toolBarHeight)+"px";

               if ( ($(document.body).height()+bid_toolBarHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $bid_toolBar.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: bid_toolBarTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $bid_toolBar.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }

       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionbid_toolBar)
               .resize(positionbid_toolBar)

});
```

Comment: What part you didn't get Ben

Comment: Im tryna understand this code,.. used this but not sure which part I need to change apart from #bid_toolBar

Comment: done, does it mean that I have to remove 

position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

in my css.?

Comment: yes remove the css and show me your css code if any

Comment: it's just the same... 

`.bid-toolbar {
 background:#FFCD2F !important;
 height:70px !important;
  /*  position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);*/
}`

Comment: yea that works... but i'm confused it doesn't work here on Intel XDK

Comment: do you have jQuery linked to your page?

Comment: Yea I do... I'll create jsfiddle

Comment: Yea I do... linked to my page

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Or this was actually just the device/browser issues.

Comment: I'm using intel XDK... not sure if it's the case cus I've tried a few methods...and tested on the emulator

Comment: Not sure about intel XDK. Probably this might help > [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/621742)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful